# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin: 3.0.0-M4 (default-test). There are test failures- JENKINS

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation, automated-tests, devops

[image: Latest Result][image: POM.XML]I did download the project from github without any problem, i provided th maven commands mvn clean install and the project build successfully but when it comes to run the tests i get the following error. Any hints? I'am providing my pom.xml file, i tried all the suggestions but nothing.

[image: Failed Jenkins Result]

Comment: Scroll up in the log output and check what the reason for the failure is...

Answer (score 0):

Does your pom.xml contains the plugin surefire tag ? If thats missing then maven wont download this plugin at runtime and hence the error. Also if its there but maven cant download then may be you have to allow internet connectivity or copy the jars manually inside the .m2 directory on the Jenkins/Node server machine.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes Sir, i do have the surefire plugin, i also tried to change the version, but did not work let me try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Yes sir, actually on my pom.xml file  i have maven sure fire plugin 3.0.0.M4, I really do not know where Jenkins is getting that from.

Comment: Hello guys, I just found out why i was getting this error. Since i use mac, Jenkins could not access my driver because on the path it self there is a small space that jenkins could not understand. Removing that little space form path location of the driver problem solved. Thanks for your attention.